# How to use a custom pandoc HTML template in bookdown::gitbook

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I'd like to write a custom template for a bookdown project. From the [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html#gitbook-style) of the bookdown package I read that it is possible to replace the default template with a custom one, say `my_custom_template.html`, by including `template: "my_custom_template.html"` in the YAML header like

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  template: my_custom_template.html
```

Doing so yields the following error:

```
Error in rmarkdown::html_document(..., extra_dependencies = c(extra_dependencies,  : 
  formal argument "template" matched by multiple actual arguments
Calls: <Anonymous> ... do.call -> <Anonymous> -> html_document2 -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  Failed to compile the book to bookdown::gitbook
```

It seems to me that the default template is hardcoded and thus cannot be overriden that easily.

Is there another way to include a custom template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: This has become possible since [**bookdown** v0.8](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/releases/tag/v0.8) (thanks to the PR [#570](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/pull/570)).

---

This is not possible, and it is documented this way: In the documentation for the used function (`?bookdown::gitbook`) `template` is excluded from the list of available parameters to be passed to `rmarkdown::html_document()`, along with `toc` and `theme`. This is also mentioned in the page you are linking to:

> There are a few arguments of html_document() that have been hard-coded
> in gitbook() and you cannot change them: toc = TRUE (there must be a
> table of contents), theme = NULL (not using any Bootstrap themes), and
> template (there exists an internal GitBook template).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I totally overlooked this passage.