# Minor change to existing bookdown template, how to set a custom templates/default.html

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I have a minor change to make to the bookdown template that I'm pretty sure can't be achieved with the existing options so I'd like to make a minor tweak to the HTML template without otherwise affecting things. From the manual, I can see that the default template is 'default.html' which I can locate in the package directories.

https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html#bootstrap-style

But the manual just has the following about how this file is specified without the context of where this code normally lives and how you might customise it:

```
html_chapters(toc = TRUE, number_sections = TRUE,
  fig_caption = TRUE, lib_dir = "libs",
  template = bookdown_file("templates/default.html"), # <<<<<------ HERE
  pandoc_args = NULL, ...,
  base_format = rmarkdown::html_document,
  split_bib = TRUE, page_builder = build_chapter,
  split
```

How do I specify a custom: 'templates/default.html' in my YAML without changing anything else?

if I do:

```
---
...
output: 
  bookdown::gitbook:
    template: my-template.html
---
```

Where my-template.html is an unedited copy of 'templates/default.html' in my project root It breaks the styling. Is there a YAML config that will let me set this without breaking the styling?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a custom pandoc HTML template in bookdown::gitbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52316862/how-to-use-a-custom-pandoc-html-template-in-bookdowngitbook)

Comment: No I used this method in my question making `my-template.html` a copy of `templates/default.html` breaks the styling of the output. I'm looking for a way to specify a path to a tweaked `templates/default.html` without any other effects. I could achieve this by forking bookdown and editing `templates/default.html` in my version but I'm looking for a YAML option to override the default instead so it's more maintainable.

Comment: The `template` argument to `gitbook()` is hard-coded – it cannot be overridden.

Comment: @M.A. That's no longer true. I just updated the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52317533/559676. I don't know why I didn't see this post in 2018, but anyway, the `template` argument has become customizable for two years. Thanks!

Comment: Heck, that would have saved me a lot of time! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the output format `bookdown::gitbook`, it *does not* use the template

```r
bookdown:::bookdown_file("templates/default.html")
```

but

```r
bookdown:::bookdown_file('templates', 'gitbook.html')
```

instead. You should make modifications based on [this `gitbook.html` template](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/inst/templates/gitbook.html).

The template `default.html` is primarily for the Bootstrap style.